# how to make int random number

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, integer

hey there im trying to make a random tree spawner script and was wondering how i could make the "number" int random i tried to o it like i did with the x and z int any help would be much appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class randomspawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tree;
    public int number;
    public int yaxis;

    void Start()
    {
        PlaceTree();
    }
    void PlaceTree()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(tree, GeneratedPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }



    Vector3 GeneratedPosition()
    {
        int x, y, z;
        x = Random.Range(-1000, 1000);
        y = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-yaxis, yaxis);
        z = Random.Range(-1000, 1000);
        return new Vector3(x, y, z);

    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with making `number` random the same way you did with `x and z`?

Comment: i did try that multiple ways but i dont know how to swap that out with the  for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) code

Comment: Could you add more details? How did you try? can you show the code? Did you try to debug it? What error did you get? What was the output? What exactly went wrong?

Comment: i changed the "public int number" to a private and put "int number = Random.Range(10, 100);" in the start function. it saved fine and i had no errors poping up it just would not load any trees

Comment: thank you for the help i was able to get it working eventully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just do something like:
`public int number = Random.range([min], [max])`?

[min] and [max] being the values you want to choose a random number between

EDIT: You should create a constructor for the class, so when you create the object of the class, the value gets assigned to the object and it is used throught all the methods.

Another option for you is to just assign the random value to the number before the for loop is called in the function.

```cs
void PlaceTree()
{
    this.number = Random.range([min], [max]);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(tree, GeneratedPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried that but i didnt know how to transfer that over to the  for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) code

Comment: I edited my answer for more detailed answer with more options

Answer (score 0):

Can do it inside the method:

```
void PlaceTree()
{
    number = Random.Range(-1000, 1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(tree, GeneratedPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Or in Constructor:

```
public randomspawn() {
 number = Random.Range(-1000, 1000);
}
```

Comment: for each of these i got an error saying " Cannot create an instance of the static class 'Random'"

Comment: dont worry i was able to get it working thank you for the help though